# if statement not working when table = uri

Tags: php, mysql

I have an if statement that when my mysql table = the server uri, it changes the css class, but I haven't been able to get it to work. Here is my code:

```
    $adminresults = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM menu_admin WHERE position="l"');
    $adminresults_array = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($adminresults)) {
        $img = $row["img"];
        $href = $row["location"];
        $text = $row["name"];
        $uri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
        if ($href == $uri){
        $output .= "<li class='active'><a href='$CFG->wwwroot/{$href}'><p class='cssimg'><img src='$CFG->wwwroot/theme/{$img}'/></p><p class='csstxt'>{$text}</p></a></li>";
        } else {
    $output .= "<li><a href='$CFG->wwwroot/{$href}'><p class='cssimg'><img src='$CFG->wwwroot/theme/{$img}'/></p><p class='csstxt'>{$text}</p></a></li>";
        }
}
}
echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='/theme/css/styles.css' type='text/css'>
<div id='leftmain'>
<div class='cssmenu' align='left'>
<ul>{$output}</ul>
</div>
</div>";
```

the location would be the filename or path to filename  for example sitefolder/file.php

Comment: REQUEST_URI had the leading "/" ... try `if ("/".$href == $uri)`

Comment: `not working` means? what output you are getting?

Comment: have you initialized $output first ? to use it here  -> $output .=

Comment: @Ansipants...Have you debug ?..Echo both variables and check it is same.

Comment: I've added the output. I debugged the $uri, but i should have checked the $href. It actually echos all of the locations loop. Any syggestions?

Comment: `{$CFG->wwwroot}` try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` includes a slash at the start of the uri, whereas your `$href` variable doesn't.

Perhaps use `ltrim` on the server uri before comparison. Something like this:

```
$uri = ltrim($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'/');
```

Comment: no good. I've been able to pin point that it has something to do with being in a loop.

Comment: You say you've debugged the loop, so if you echo $href and $uri every time you go through the loop, what *exactly* are these variables set to each time?

Comment: $href echos the location from the specific row so the $output will create an array of the rows, $uri obviously has nothing to do with the loop itself, so that only has 1 outcome. If i echo $href, it will echo the location results from all of the tables that are pulling through the loop. So let's say row 1= filename1.php, row 2= filename2.php, row 3 = filename3.php, echoing the href would show filename1.phpfilename2.phpfilename3.php Hope this makes sense...

Comment: You should echo them both at the same time with some separators so you can clearly see what is being echoed. Something like this: `echo '('.$href.'|'.$uri.')';` You should then see `(filename1.php|currentpage.php)(filename2.php|currentpage.php)` etc. One of those filenames has to match the current page, or it should be obvious why it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, i was able to get it to work by changing the changing active to .selected in my css and this: `if ($href == $uri) {
  $i = 'selected';
 } else {
  $i = NULL;
 }` and obviously adding li class=$i to the output line